# CloudFront signing urls from Zencoder

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I'm relatively new to AWS and Zencoder, so I'm hoping someone with experience using these two services together can help me with an issue I'm running into.

I'm using a private CloudFront distribution for delivery, and I'm not having any luck playing signed CloudFront urls of the video files that come from Zencoder (owner of the files are zencodertv).  I get an access denied XML message.  If I manually upload files into the S3 bucket that is the source of the CloudFront distribution (the same bucket that Zencoder is feeding), my signed files play just fine.  I'm assuming the issue is due to the fact that I'm not the owner of the file - is that correct?

I see that Zencoder has a "public" option, but I don't want my videos publicly accessibly in either S3 or Cloudfront.  Maybe I need to create a bucket specifically for transcoded files coming from Zencoder and then make use of copy_object (I'm using AWS's PHP SDK) to move the file to the final/private S3 bucket.  That seems like overkill though.  Thoughts?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Found a solution. If you enter your S3 access credentials in to Zencoder then it will upload the file to your bucket as you, and CloudFront works. You can also remove the bucket policy.

Comment: Wish I could +100 this.  I've been struggling trying to figure this out until I realized that the only videos that worked were the ones I had encoded & uploaded myself.  All the files zencoder uploaded wouldn't work.  Thanks!